# Excel: get text value of non-hidden cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

This formula

```
SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($F$5,ROW($F$5:$F$400)-ROW($F$5),0))
```

gives an array of 0 for those cells that are hidden and 1 for those not hidden.

What I'd like to have is an array of 0 or blank for hidden cells and the cell value, which is text, for those non-hidden cells.

What formula would do that?

The following pictures are an example. If I filter column 1 by selecting 1. Then, only Apple, Pineapple, and Banana will appear on screen. The rest will be hidden. I need this array: {"Apple","","","",Pineapple,"","Banana","",""}.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sumproduct would be a good fit, but I suggest you edit your question and post some sample data so we can help you better

Comment: I have edited the question to add two pictures. Hope the question is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative to count visibile `Banana`:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B10="Banana")*(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(B2,ROW(B2:B10)-2,0))))
```

[image]

This answer is based on [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria) website which gives you bit more of background information as to why would this work.

Comment: Thank you. I like this one because it doesn't need to press Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 1):

To get text value of non-hidden cells

Try this array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) :

```
=TRANSPOSE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($F$5,ROW($F$5:INDEX($F$5:$F$400,COUNTA($F$5:$F$400)))-ROW($F$5),0))=1,F5:INDEX($F$5:$F$400,COUNTA($F$5:$F$400)),""))
```

Which will return an array result :

```
={"Apple","","","","Pineapple","","Banana","",""}
```

And,

To count the number of "Banana"

Try this array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) :

```
=SUM(0+(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($F$5,ROW($F$5:INDEX($F$5:$F$400,COUNTA($F$5:$F$400)))-ROW($F$5),0))=1,F5:INDEX($F$5:$F$400,COUNTA($F$5:$F$400)),"")="Banana"))
```

Which will return `1` in your example

Remark :

1] The SUBTOTAL+OFFSET formula originally return a row array result.  Since you required a column array result, so adding a TRANSPOSE() to convert the row array to column array in the 1st formula.

2]  The 2nd formula is a count number formula, row or column array will give the same result, so the TRANSPOSE() is not required.

Comment: Thanks. That works. How do I take it one more step to count the number of, say, banana, in the array. I thought I could just wrap the array in a COUNTIF something like COUNTIF(the-array,"Banana"), but that did not work.

Comment: To count the number of Banana, please see the reply new edited formula